# Failed to run application

Tags: swift, macos

When I'm running app it gives the build target failed with these issues, but when I run my app to another mac it runs successfully. What's the issue?

> Ld
>   /Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TailorMade.app/TailorMade
>   normal i386
>       cd "/Users/defuzed/Desktop/prachi projects/5-Sept/TailorMade"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode
>   2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking
>   -F/Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast-Swift
>   -filelist /Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/TailorMade.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TailorMade.build/Objects-normal/i386/TailorMade.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.3 -Xlinker
>   -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework AFNetworking -framework Toast_Swift -L/Applications/Xcode\
>   2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/TailorMade.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TailorMade.build/Objects-normal/i386/TailorMade.swiftmodule
>   -framework AVFoundation -framework AVKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreBluetooth -framework Security -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreFoundation -framework AFNetworking -framework Pods_TailorMade -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker
>   /Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/TailorMade.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TailorMade.build/Objects-normal/i386/TailorMade_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TailorMade.app/TailorMade

---

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking,
>   file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked
>   (i386):
>   /Users/defuzed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestSerializer", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.AFHTTPRequestSerializer in WS.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.AFHTTPSessionManager in WS.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.AFJSONResponseSerializer in WS.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode Select Window > Projects > Your Project > Delete Derived data